# MySQL UNION truncating returned datasets

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT current_raised,segment FROM gizmos
where created_at >= "2012-03-01"
```

returns 600+ rows

```
SELECT "current_raised","segment"
UNION
(SELECT current_raised,segment FROM gizmos
where created_at >= "2012-03-01")
```

returns 180 rows

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`union` will remove from the result set every duplicated `current_raised, segment` pair. Try `union all` instead.

Here is a reduced [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27db2/2) of what is happening.

Comment: @MM -- thanks.  I just stumbled across that difference as well .. but thanks for the answer.  AND thanks for pointing me to SQLFIDDLE -- that SH!T is sweet

Answer (score -1):

It's a slightly confusing feature of standard SQL: the default qualifier for `SELECT` is `SELECT ALL` but the default qualifier for `UNION` is `UNION DISTINCT`.

Your first query is implicitly using `SELECT ALL` and is returning duplicate rows in the result, not good. Correct the first query by explicitly using `SELECT DISTINCT`.